# How to make dropdown extends the outer div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My drop down is wrapped inside a div and this div is wrapped inside another div. I want the most outer div to have a scroll bar when necessary. However, since the most outer div has a fixed height, when the drop down menu is too long, it will be covered by the outer div. How can I make that drop down go beyond the outer div or is is possible to change to a drop up automatically whenever the drop down menu is covered by the outer div?

```css
.widget-body {
  position: relative;
}
.widget-body .col-xs-2.open {
  position: static;
}
.widget-body ul.dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-body" style="border: solid 1px black; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y: auto;height:100px; margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
  <div class="widget-main" id="ds_div">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="widget-body" style="border: solid 1px black; height:45px; margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:20px; background:linear-gradient(to right, #85e2f0 5% , white 95%);">
          <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:45px; font-size: 28px;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:30px;text-align:center; border: solid 1px black;margin-top: 6px; display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center; background-color: #42d442;">test</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:43px; font-size: 27px; text-align: center;">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code above doesn't work properly, so here is another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5zszwktw/7)

Comment: Apparently there is a scroll bar appears to the outer div when we click on the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, I need that scroll bar! And I need the drop down menu to either go extends the outer div  or 'drop up' so that the content of the drop down is not clipped.

Comment: Your outer div is already scrolling properly once drop down menu opens.

Comment: I do need the scroll bar when there are too many inner divs (the inner divs in my app are created dynamically). Now, my problem is when I click the drop  down, the drop down menu is clipped by the outer div. So I need to make the drop down menu extend the div just like the effect when I remove the overflow-x.

Comment: So post the code when dynamic div are added and then show us the situation.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle demo to show you when I need the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

When I have taken out the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` from the **widget-body**, I can see the dropdown menu came out.

Check this modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zszwktw/3/)

Comment: I do need this overflow-y attribute when there are too much content inside!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using div to cover your outer layer, you could use table to control the structure.

```
<table border="1px" width="1080" height="1080">
<tr>
<td>
  <div class="widget-main" id="ds_div">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="widget-body" style="border: solid 1px black; height:45px; margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:20px;background:linear-gradient(to right, #85e2f0 5% , white 95%);">
      <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:45px; font-size: 28px;">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:30px;text-align:center; border: solid 1px black;margin-top: 6px; display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center; background-color: #42d442;">test</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:43px; font-size: 27px; text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                 </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Not the best answer, but i think i would help.